# How do I convert date from alphabetical to numeric format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert date from 'Sep 17, 2021' format to '17.09.2021'. I made a function, but I can't apply it to the series. What am I doing wrong?

```
def to_normal_date(bad_date):
    datetime.strptime(bad_date, '%b %d, %Y')
    return s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df['normal_date'] = df['date'].apply(to_normal_date)
```

I receive a ValueError when I'm trying to apply it to series. But it works fine with this:

```
to_normal_date('Sep 16, 2021')
```

Comment: Can you post details printed with the ValueError? Are you sure all df['date'] entries match the date pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `pd.to_datetime` to convert the "date" column to datetime format. Specifying `errors="coerce"` will convert dates that are not in the correct format to `NaN` values instead of raising errors.
2. Convert to the required format using `.strftime` with the `.dt` accessor.

```
df["normal_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%b %d, %Y", errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

>>> df
           date normal_date
0  Sep 17, 2021  17.09.2021
1  Oct 31, 2021  31.10.2021
2  Nov 19, 2021  19.11.2021
3  Dec 25, 2021  25.12.2021
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me! So my problem was in this: errors="coerce". Because I already converted "date" column to datetime format.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d, %Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

It should work provided all `df['date']` entries match the date pattern of 'Sep 17, 2021'.

Comment: I tried it, but I receive an error, too. It says 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: @Melissa My bad I was casting into datetime the wrong way, please try my updated proposal.